# Does Azure auto index tables?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are noticing unexpected indexes appearing in our database tables on Azure. We are not explicitly calling these out during table creation. Does Azure auto add indexes for any reason that we can see somewhere?

Comment: Seems like it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automatic-tuning-overview?view=azuresql#automatic-tuning-options

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automatic-tuning-overview?view=azuresql#automatic-tuning-options),  and you can disable that feature by going into Intelligent Performance > Automatic tuning

[image]